# Texto en las filas (row) de una lista en menu se corta en algunos dispositivos

Tags: android, menú

gracias por vuestra ayuda. Android/android studio.

En mi app tengo filas de menu que tienen un titulo y un subtitulo debajo a modo de descripción. En algunos dispositivos se ven perfectas todas las filas, pero en otros las lineas debajo del titulo de cada fila se cortan. No parece tener que ver con el tamaño de la pantalla tras probarlo en varios dispositivos. la verdad es que estoy perdido.

Por favor, alguna ayuda?

Adjunto fotos para mejor comprensión.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1eaii7r9i68xx0/IMG_20170312_130213.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpcakt5vqnj454c/IMG_20170312_130239.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Es debido a la resolución de los dispositivos, puedes ver la documentación aquí:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Debes utilizar distintos valores de dimensiones en los archivos `dimen.xml` de las distintas configuraciones y distintos layouts para las distintas resoluciones.

Por ejemplo las carpetas de recursos `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, etc, que contengan distintos layouts y las carpetas `values-hdpi`, `values-xhdpi`, etc , que contengan distintos archivos `dimen.xml`